# Immunoglobulin E (IgE) level and covid vaccine

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, side-effects

I am finding hard to find information if a person has say higher than average level of Immunoglobulin E (IgE) is it safe to do covid vaccine?

Comment: I googled it (elevated IgE levels and covid vaccine) and got a lot of info from multiple sites. What did you find when you googled it?

Comment: @anongoodnurse Can you share few links then? I found only some YouTube videos in Indian language.

Comment: I entered the same query @anongoodnurse used and found entries like [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7999280/) and [this](https://www.entnet.org/resource/allergic-reactions-related-to-covid-19-vaccinations-in-allergic-patients/) and [this](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/nejmra2035343). There are more.

Comment: @CareyGregory Can you highlight at least few sentences which talk in those links **exactly** about whether it is safe or not to do vaccine given high ige level?

Comment: This site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. Just some indication that you at least tried to find the answer yourself. I offered those links to demonstrate that there's plenty of into out there that you say you can't find, and also to help you get started on your research. Me reading the links won't improve your question, which is in danger of being closed due to lack of prior reseach.

Comment: @CareyGregory The links you provided do not contain information about what I am looking for, **can you prove me wrong**?

Comment: @CareyGregory Is this site only about parsing scientific articles? I was looking for info which might not be hidden behind scientific articles, and say presented in a more layman understandable way. Even in that case, the links you give IMHO don't contain info on what I am looking for

Comment: The point of those links I gave you was to help get you started. Your claim that there is no information on the question is not true. Most of what's out there may be above the laymen level of understanding, but this site may be as well. As for posting only scientific articles, no, that's not true at all. You're required to write your own questions and answers, but we also require you to provide references to support your claims of fact. I think you would benefit from reading the [help] and taking the [tour]. You might also want to read [ask].

Comment: Google gives different results in different countries, but @CareyGregory provided links to information which is easy enough to understand. It's easy to ask for the summary, but that's not the way this site works. What did **you** find when you read the links? If you have questions about what you read, we would be happy to clear them up (or try.) :)

Comment: @anongoodnurse Well, yes a short summary would be very useful for me

Comment: As I stated, that's not the way this site works. When you read the links, if you have questions about what you read, we would be happy to clear them up (or try.) :)  (You can read the fable about Hercules and the cartman/wagoner to help you understand SE's position on this matter.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse Ok have a nice day!